# How to configure cdn path on index.html in angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular6

I'm a beginner with angular. I started with angular 6 and am currently unable to understand how to make configurable cdn paths with my index.html in angular project.

Please have a look at my code ::

```html
 <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Refman</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn1.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn2.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>

    <app-root></app-root>
    
</body>
</html>
```

I want to make these cdn1 and cdn2 configurable. This means I want to read the cdn path and base url of the cdn from my config.json. How to read them with this path from the .json file.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In one of your component, you'd need to read the config value and dynamically add/modify the `link` tag using dom manipulation

Comment: Hi David thanks for reply i read in my component now i am using those key in {{ }} in head tag but its not working please suggest me

Comment: It will not work like this, you need to do it dynamically from a component

Answer (score 1):

Angular suggest Environment variable to manage dynamic variable and configuration like your requirement.

environment.ts

environment.prod.ts

.... custom environment

for more information :
https://medium.com/@balramchavan/separating-production-and-development-http-urls-using-environment-ts-file-in-angular-4c2dd0c5a8b0

http://tattoocoder.com/angular-cli-using-the-environment-option/

https://medium.com/@amcdnl/custom-environments-for-angular-cli-4ce0b82da83b

structure :

https://angular.io/guide/quickstart#the-src-folder

Comment: I did that but how i read my key  in href of link please suggest me

Comment: @SatyamShukla try this : <link rel="stylesheet" [href=]"variablename">, I suggest you put environment.key into a variable at component.ts and then read it in your html

Comment: @SatyamShukla in previous comment was a mistake [href=] is wrong and [href]= is correct one

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the environment class to your component where your index.html is located:

```
import { environment } from 'location of environment.ts'
```

Then you pass the class variable this way:

```
public pName = environment.propertyname; // .css or a URL
```

In your index.html, you pass pName to href:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="pName">
```

Comment: Thanks but its not working i am able to set property in pName but this line <link rel="stylesheet" href="pName">  is not working for me

Comment: try placing href inside [ ]  - like this [href]="pName"